# The Spectrum of Finite Rank Operator

Tags: functional-analysis

I know that 0 is always in the spectrum of finite rank operator (because it is compact and we can use Fredholm thm.). But every operator on finite dimension space is finite rank and thus we get that 0 is always in the spectrum of operator on finite dimesion space which is completely nonsense because there is only $\sigma_p$.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2):

The identity on $\mathbb{C}^n$ is of finite rank and its spectrum is exactly $\{ 1 \}$. So your claim that " $0$ is always in the spectrum of a finite rank operator" is false.

If the underlying vector space is infinite-dimensional *then* $0$ is in the spectrum of any compact (and thus finite-rank) operator. This is a consequence of the fact that the unit-ball is only pre-compact in finite-dimensional spaces.

Also: For compact operators there is *not* "only $\sigma_p$" - in general the spectral theorem for compacts doesn't tell you if $0$ is an eigenvalue. Only in the finite dimensional case you know that the spectrum consists solely of eigenvalues.

Comment: But if the operator is of finite rank and $\dim X = \infty$, then $0$ is necessary an eigenvalue. This follows from the algebraic identity $\dim \ker T + \dim \operatorname{ran} T = \dim X$ for any linear map $T$ on $X$.